# Java SSL handshake always get "PKIX path building failed" for any domain

Tags: java, ssl

I get this error message when build a gradle project in idea:

```
      > Could not resolve io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.6.RELEASE.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/spring/gradle/dependency-management-plugin/1.0.6.RELEASE/dependency-management-plugin-1.0.6.RELEASE.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/spring/gradle/dependency-management-plugin/1.0.6.RELEASE/dependency-management-plugin-1.0.6.RELEASE.pom'.
               > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I found that all ssl handshack in java get the same error.

I use [SSLPoke](https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029) to check some domains, such as  stackoverflow.com, github.com, all of them return the same error message: "PKIX path building failed". But I can visit this sites on the browser with no error.

I try to change the jdk from jdk11 to jdk8, and try to reinstall the jdk, but also get the same result. I check the default jdk keystore by `keytool -list` command, and it looks like no problem.

I try to debug and found that the certificate looks weird, it only has one cert in the cert chain, and the Issuer is always `CN=GlobalSign Root CA, C=EN`, no matter which domain. Such as stackoverflow.com:

```
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=*.stackexchange.com
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 129343236870246922217917428341848371602010941604981692235450252202393431416169367447480541321401904173442212978999107322095875009215075266308069463921433338673265672174736174633404814882397952490528363553362969976277321592285699339620492251079789709609773064124868826755702755848122392099215387700370904957487
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Fri Jul 26 22:38:33 CST 2019,
               To: Thu Oct 24 22:38:33 CST 2019]
  Issuer: CN=GlobalSign Root CA, C=EN
  SerialNumber: [    bae8be0e 04cb0e2b 0e83d26f c22ba1e7]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: *.askubuntu.com
  DNSName: *.blogoverflow.com
  DNSName: *.mathoverflow.net
  DNSName: *.meta.stackexchange.com
  DNSName: *.meta.stackoverflow.com
  DNSName: *.serverfault.com
  DNSName: *.sstatic.net
  DNSName: *.stackexchange.com
  DNSName: *.stackoverflow.com
  DNSName: *.stackoverflow.email
  DNSName: *.superuser.com
  DNSName: askubuntu.com
  DNSName: blogoverflow.com
  DNSName: mathoverflow.net
  DNSName: openid.stackauth.com
  DNSName: serverfault.com
  DNSName: sstatic.net
  DNSName: stackapps.com
  DNSName: stackauth.com
  DNSName: stackexchange.com
  DNSName: stackoverflow.blog
  DNSName: stackoverflow.com
  DNSName: stackoverflow.email
  DNSName: stacksnippets.net
  DNSName: superuser.com
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: B5 35 45 AA 8D 99 FF F1   3F 5D CA 94 6D 5F 6A 12  .5E.....?]..m_j.
0010: D2 39 0E 66 1D 11 63 80   12 0C A1 2D A7 CA A7 39  .9.f..c....-...9
0020: 36 4B A4 12 45 AD A8 4D   E5 1E DD 7B AF A9 10 CD  6K..E..M........
0030: ED 5B 15 76 F2 49 41 F8   AB 82 67 5D E8 09 0A 65  .[.v.IA...g]...e
0040: 7D BC 22 C5 53 7D DD 32   15 9E 88 92 FB 35 C2 C8  ..".S..2.....5..
0050: 86 E0 53 BF 32 72 DA FA   CE 27 A0 BA 78 5F DA B2  ..S.2r...'..x_..
0060: CA C3 8B 14 0B C5 EF E1   4D 96 8F BF 4A AC B0 DB  ........M...J...
0070: 24 5E 20 7C 32 51 58 93   36 0B 1A 2A BB 88 A3 9B  $^ .2QX.6..*....
0080: DF 6F B4 F1 25 CD B8 C6   C1 1D 19 BD A7 54 27 73  .o..%........T's
0090: 56 A8 5D 78 13 E6 86 00   59 E2 32 34 34 28 6D 4F  V.]x....Y.244(mO
00A0: 30 39 F6 3A 2E 43 1F E6   7B 43 57 C2 79 E5 87 4C  09.:.C...CW.y..L
00B0: CB 9E 95 6D 99 6D 46 AD   FA 7D 74 BA 12 D9 D0 8B  ...m.mF...t.....
00C0: 93 B7 49 E4 61 FD 4B 73   00 FA 0E 61 9A 4E DA C1  ..I.a.Ks...a.N..
00D0: D3 B9 45 B1 79 13 BB 90   02 98 24 E7 4D 31 01 52  ..E.y.....$.M1.R
00E0: 1F 38 47 0B 4E 4C E0 91   2A 8A 05 6E 20 89 81 E3  .8G.NL..*..n ...
00F0: 3B E3 60 D5 70 DF 28 D3   58 E7 D6 FF A6 CA 1D B6  ;.`.p.(.X.......

]
```

Different to the normal cert:

- Key length. Normal is 2048 bits, not 1024 bits.
- Issuer. Normal is `CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3, O=Let's Encrypt, C=US`
- Certificate Extensions. Normal has 9 extensions, not 3.
- modulus, SerialNumber, Signature. Their value is different to the normal.
- Normal cert has a intermediate certificate in the cert chain, Issuer is `CN=DST Root CA X3, O=Digital Signature Trust Co.`

So, how can I find the real reason of the problem, and how to solve the problem.

Comment: That's clearly bogus; the transparency logs (per crt.sh) don't know any cert for that Issuer name, EN is not even a valid value for the Country attribute, and no public root CA would directly issue server certs. What kind of Internet connection are you using -- private home, business or other employer, school, shared apartment building, etc? Can you try another, like say a Starbucks? Are you in a country that mandates 'monitoring'? Is this your computer or device? Which browser(s)? Does it/them and/or the OS (if IE/Edge Chrome Safari) have a bogus 'GlobalSign' root installed?

Comment: I have tried to change another internet connection, but get the same result. Other people in the same network works fine in java. I have checked the cert chain of some sites in firefox, chrome, ie, edge, all of them have the right root CA, not the "GlobalSign Root CA". I found that request to different site can get different certificate response in java, with the same Issuer "GlobalSign Root CA", and same site can get the same certificate in different request.

Comment: I have found a CA has the Issuer "CN = GlobalSign Root CA, C = EN" in the system certificate store, it's name is "GlobalSign Root CA - R1", fingerprint is "2fe78d16e75b9fd90648ddc632221e099ec3c4ab". But not found it in firefox. I delete it, but nothing change. Maybe I need to reset my windows os or reinstall it?

Comment: So Java always sees bad cert (apparently intercepted) but (all?) browsers always see good? Weird. I don't know of anything in Windows that could do that, but try it if you want to be sure. I would try tracing a few examples (my preference is Wireshark) and look in detail for any relevant differences, but that will be some work. PS to be clear: there are legitimate GlobalSign roots, just not the one you have, which suggests someone trying to conceal by misdirection.

Comment: I use Wireshark to catch the handshake info. Java and broswer have received the same certificates from server. And I found that I can success connect to a site after connect fail to the same site several times. I check some fail connection and the first success connection in Wireshark. The difference between them is the success connection has a session id in the client hello message. The success handshake is a abbreviated handshake, all fail handshake are full handshake.

Comment: An abbreviated handshake can _only_ be done following a successful full handshake for that same session. I bet if you look closely you have something like browser-full-good-session=X, java-full-fail, browser-abbr-good-session=X. So if browser-full and java-full receive the same certs, and Java rejects them, and browser accepts them but displays them as different than Java received, who is wrong? Is browser displaying what it received, or not? Is Java displaying what it received, or not?

Comment: I log a success and a fail connection with `javax.net.debug=all param` and catch their packages, [file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xXutih3oUMo0bYZaxPl_1HrO58-Lzxtc/view?usp=sharing). See line 3638 in the fail log, the raw read bytes is different to the first five bytes of `Transport Layer Security`  in the server hello response. In success log, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Meta: not an answer yet but need space to respond to data

Aside: I assume you are in timezone +8. The PCAPs are 09-18 01:43:00-01 and 01:49:52-54 Z
while the Java-log timestamps are 09-18 09:42:59-43:01 and 09:49:51-54 CST.

First, the Java-logs. In the success log at line 3652, the ServerHello selects TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 
and agrees to extensions renegotiation_info server_name ec_point_formats status_request extended_master_secret;
this is consistent with the real stackoverflow servers in my testing. In the fail log at 3651,
it selects TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 and agrees to only renegotiation_info ec_point_formats,
which is substantially different behavior. We then see the different certificates, 
with success.txt getting the correct leaf cert (under Let's Encrypt) and chain cert (under DST),
and fail.txt getting the bogus cert under "CN=GlobalSign Root CA, C=EN" with most extensions missing, and no chain.

But as to the PCAPs:

> See line 3638 in the fail log, the raw read bytes is different to the first five bytes of Transport Layer Security in the server hello response. In success log, they are the same.

That's not the only difference. Although the time matches, 
**your fail.PCAP doesn't match your fail.txt at all**. Most importantly, it doesn't fail -- 
it receives the correct cert chain (Let's Encrypt + DST) and completes the handshake successfully.
In more detail:

- the ClientHello is very different. It offers max TLS1.2, not TLS1.3 as offered by (your) Java.
  It has a different list of ciphersuites, and different extensions (necessarily so for 1.2 vs 1.3), 
  among which are Heartbeat and ticket neither of which Java supports.
- the ServerHello is shorter (record header 16 03 03 00 45 vs 16 03 03 00 59 in the fail.txt or 16 03 03 00 65 in the success.txt, 
  as you noticed) because it offered ticket and the server agreed, and thus the server does not provide a session-id.
- (as above) it gets the good certs, as well as CertStatus ServerKX ServerDone, 
  and proceeds to send ClientKX CCS Finished and receive ticket CCS Finished -- i.e. success.
- your client soon (but not instantly) RSTs without sending (or receiving) any data; this is the behavior of a Windows program that closes without doing shutdown (perhaps due to being killed) or a Unix program that explicitly sets linger=0 (which is unusual).

I also notice the fail.PCAP connection goes to 151.101.65.69 but the success.PCAP goes to 151.101.193.69. 
Both of those addresses (and two others) are valid for stackoverflow.com, but usually connections 
from the same machine within a short time window like this would resolve to and use the same address.

Look carefully at what you did for the fail.PCAP and see if you can get a PCAP that actually is a failure case.
Actually, an idea occurs here. **DO YOU HAVE AN ANTIVIRUS OR OTHER 'ENDPOINT PROTECTION'?** That might intercept the outgoing connection before it leaves your machine, so that the *program* (Java) sees the bogus cert even though the *correct* cert was actually fetched from the network. But there would still need to be a reason it intercepts one connection and not another.